# Laravel 5.4 - Issue with query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a table called "Characters". Each row is identified by / has a primary key called char_id. I have routes and templates working as well as some controllers with some CRUD, so Laravel is working fine.

I want to be able to display a row, identified by the rows id, when a user goes to "character/{char_id}" eg "character/2".

I have the following code in my web route:

```
Route::get('characters/{char_id}', function($char_id) {
    $character = \DB::table('characters')->find($char_id);
    dd($character);
});
```

But when I visit "characters/1" or any other number I get this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `characters` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

It seems to be looking for a column called "id" regardless of what I try to pass from the URL. I'm following a tutorial that uses "id" so I suspect my code is looking for a column called "id" but I don't know how to get around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because by default find checks the `id` column, the easiest way to fix this without using models is to make the where yourself :

```
 $character = \DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', $char_id)->first();
```

However, if you have a Character model, you can just set :

```
protected $primaryKey = 'char_id';
```

and then use find :

```
App\Character::find($char_id);
```

Comment: "by default" implies that you can change it. You can't. Find explicitly compares against an `id` column. You can only change it by extending the `Builder` class and redefining the `find` method.

Comment: Not if you use a model, as I just added

Comment: Indeed, but then you're using ActiveRecord, not just DBAL.

Comment: True, because eloquent doesn't use the same query builder, but it's still a way to do what he wants easily. But yeah, I get your point, English is not my mother tongue

Comment: All good, I just wanted to point out to any reader that it's not an option :)

Comment: Cheers AlexvanVliet & @Scopey